# Spring Boot Actuator health returns proper but beans empty([])

Tags: spring-boot

Spring Boot Actuator when I hit URL health or matrices it return proper data but in case of beans URL no data found.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are hitting [this bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8146) in Spring Boot 1.4.4. It only happens when launching your application as a Spring Boot app in Eclipse. You can avoid the problem by launching it as a plain Java application instead.